# Why does my list print user input in brackets instead of what I intend to do, names?

Tags: python

I’m Trying to make a raffle winners Thing Where You Input Your “Guests”, Then, It Checks If They Are In The Raffle Winners List Or Not, Finnaly, Printing out people who won, and people who didn’t , I need help with printing out(looping thru) the names and checking it. here is my code so pls:

```
###############
import random#random
Raffle_generator=random.randint(1,4)#my random generator
if Raffle_generator==1:
  Raffle_Winners=['Bob','Alice']#random names
if Raffle_generator==2:
  Raffle_Winners=['Matt','Joe']
if Raffle_generator==3:
  Raffle_Winners=['Tim','Doug']
if Raffle_generator==4:
  Raffle_Winners=['Rick','Jim']

print('Enter Name Of Guests In This Format -> xxx,xxx,xxx.....')#formatting

Guests=(input('>')).split(‘,’)#turns it into brackets?





for RandomPerson in Raffle_Winners:#looping through the Guests, bit confused here
  if Guests in Raffle_Winners:
    print(Guests,'Has Won The Raffle!')#tells if u won
  if Guests not in Raffle_Winners:
    print(Guests,'Has Not Won The Raffle')#tells if you did not win.
#

#Bob,Alice,Matt,Joe,Tim,Doug,Rick,Jim#copy this to tests it
```

Comment: Try typing in bobh,Alice,Matt,joe and Tim,(copy paste ) -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is Wrong.
You need to iterate `Guests` list and see if the name is in `Raffle_Winners` list.

```
for Guest in Guests:
  if Guest in Raffle_Winners:
    print(Guest,' Has Won The Raffle!')
  else:
    print(Guest,' Has Not Won The Raffle')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to search each guest to see if they are a winner

```
import random
Raffle_generator=random.randint(1,4)
if Raffle_generator==1:
  Raffle_Winners=['Bob','Alice']
if Raffle_generator==2:
  Raffle_Winners=['Matt','Joe']
if Raffle_generator==3:
  Raffle_Winners=['Tim','Doug']
if Raffle_generator==4:
  Raffle_Winners=['Rick','Jim']

print('Enter Name Of Guests In This Format -> xxx,xxx,xxx.....')

Guests=(input('>')).split(',')

for guest in Guests:
    if guest in Raffle_Winners:
        print(guest.strip(), 'Has Won The Raffle!')
    else:
        print(guest.strip(), 'Has Not Won The Raffle')
```